# How to pass Model Value through ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple model which models a vehicle entity.
It has attributes:
Model
Make
Colour
RegistrationPlate

On the create View I want to users to be able to perform a server look up using the registration plate to auto fill the Model/Make/Colour information.

As such I'm trying to create an action link like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Look up registration", "RegLookup", "Vehicle", Model.Registration)
```

Where RegLookup is a get ActionResult method in the vehicle controller which goes away and finds the model/make/colour information based on the registration field passed through to it.  The Make/Model/Colour information is retrieved from a separate database.

However at present on rendering the view - before even getting to the action link - an exception is thrown indicating that the Model is Null.

What I want to be passed through is effectively the value from the textbox representing the registration:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Registration)
```

How do I pass this value through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CreateView, typically your Model Properties should mostly be empty except some prepoulated values like dropdowns . What you should use is to use jQuery ajax to make an async call to an action method which returns the relevant data based on the registration plate and fill that in the Form

You may keep the action link like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Look up registration", "RegLookup", "Vehicle",
                                                      new {@id="check"},null)
```

And attach a javascript function to the click event of it to make the ajax call

```
$(function(){

  $("#check").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var item=$(this);
    var regPlateVal=$("#RegistrationPlate").val();
    $.getJSON(item.attr("href")+"?registration="+regPlateVal,function(data){
       if(data.Status=="success")
       {
         $("#Color").val(data.Color);
         $("#Model").val(data.Model);
       }
    });
  });

});
```

Assuming your `RegLookUp` action method accept a parameter (With name `registration`) and returns the data in `JSON` format like below format

```
{
  "Status": "success",
   "Color": "Red",
   "Model": "2011"
}
```

Comment: Erg I'm slightly stuck.  How do I give the EditorFor the #RegistrationPlate name?

Comment: @ChrisNevill: I do not understand what you mean ! I recommend you to not ask new questions in the comment section. Please post it as a new question with relevant details

Comment: It's taken a while but I've finally got it working.
Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the properties in the query string:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Look up registration", 
    "RegLookup", 
    "Vehicle", 
    new {
        registration = Model.Registration
    }
)
```

and then the controller action could take this `registration` parameter:

```
public ActionResult RegLookup(string registration)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I still get the NullReferenceException on the Model object.

Comment: What `Model` object are you talking about? What is your `RegLookup` controller action doing? Is it passing a model to the view? If so did you ensure that this model is not null?

Comment: The RegLookup Controller action is never called.  The NullReferenceException occurs when the view is first rendered.

Comment: Oh then you will have to fix the controller action rendering this view. Make sure that it passes a view model to it that is not null.

Comment: I've just tried passing an empty vehicle through to the view, but the registration then didn't get bound to the registration editfor textbox.  When I clicked the action link the registration string passed through was null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a normal POST or and AJAX one to send the plate number to the server. In your view, at design time you don't have the value the user entered.

Comment: It's my understanding that I can't do a post through an Action link?  I've already used the submit button for submitting the create.  So I guess I need to use AJAX.  This seems messy for such a simple task.

Comment: @ChrisNevill, not so messy... just use the Shyju's answer... it is quite complete... just make your controller return a Json object and you are done.