# jQuery never called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm trying to implement the solution provided in this question here:
[How to pass Model Value through ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956831/how-to-pass-model-value-through-actionlink/11957013#comment15960860_11957013)

So in my view I have an action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Look up registration", "RegLookup", "Vehicle",  new {@id="check"},null)
```

And in a Javascript file I have :

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#check").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

I've cut the function down to just preventing the default action of the action link.

In the view I've also referenced the java script files

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/GetRegistrationPlate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However when I click on the action link the default method continues to fire.
What might I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one there are many syntax errors. Try this

```
$(function () {
    $("#check").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Edit: Also, change the ActionLink to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Look up registration", "RegLookup", "Vehicle", new { @id = "check" }, new { @id = "check" })
```

The first id is for the route, the second id is for the html element.

Comment: Every ( needs a ) every { needs a } and ; is just nice to have. The part to notice here is `return false;`.

Comment: Thanks I've copied that in but still the default method fires.

Comment: Edited to add new Action link that supports the html element id as well :) I missed that!